# Primeng's 'selectedItem' template does not work, it always sets the selected value to the 'field' property that was set in the AutoComplete

Tags: angular, typescript, primeng

Basically, I'm trying to utilize the selected item template for an PrimeNG's AutoComplete, but does not work. In the code below I specify in the 'selectedItem' template to format the value in a certain way. Is there something that I'm missing?

````
<p-autoComplete [formControlName]="controlModel.id"
                                [forceSelection]="true"
                                [suggestions]="httpSearchResult"
                                field="Identifier"
                                (completeMethod)="searchFromUrl($event.query)"
                                (onSelect)="setSearchBoxValue()"
                                [dropdown]="true"
                                [placeholder]="'Select ' + controlModel.displayName"
                                [multiple]="controlModel.multiple">
                    <ng-template let-searchItem pTemplate="item">
                        <ng-container *ngIf="searchItem.DisplayLabel == '' && searchItem.Identifier != ''">
                            <div class="ui-helper-clearfix">
                                <div>{{searchItem.Identifier}}</div>
                            </div>
                        </ng-container>
                        <ng-container *ngIf="searchItem.DisplayLabel != '' && searchItem.Identifier == ''">
                            <div class="ui-helper-clearfix">
                                <div>{{searchItem.DisplayLabel}}</div>
                            </div>
                        </ng-container>
                        <ng-container *ngIf="searchItem.DisplayLabel != '' && searchItem.Identifier != ''">
                            <div class="ui-helper-clearfix">
                                <div>{{searchItem.Identifier}} - {{searchItem.DisplayLabel}}</div>
                            </div>
                        </ng-container>
                    </ng-template>
                    <ng-template let-searchItem pTemplate="selectedItem">
                        <div class="ui-helper-clearfix">
                            <div>{{searchItem.Identifier}} - {{searchItem.DisplayLabel}}</div>
                        </div>
                    </ng-template>
                </p-autoComplete>```
````

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found a workaround online that will solve this problem: https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/issues/2242#issuecomment-440684864

Answer (score 1):

When you have a model class, you can define additional custom method:

```
export class User {

  name: string;
  surname: string;
  userId: string;

  get fullName(): string {
    return this.name + ' ' + this.surname + ' (' + this.userId + ')';
  }

}
```

And then use it in "field" attribute:

```
<p-autoComplete [(ngModel)]="selecteduser" [suggestions]="users" field="fullName" (completeMethod)="searchForUser($event)"></p-autoComplete>
```